# Local variable in one function changing results in an unrelated function, C++

Tags: c++, mersenne-twister

Just to forewarn folks, I'm a physicist writing a simulation which is probably toy code from a professional programmer's perspective, so my coding knowledge isn't great. Anyway, paraphrasing 700 lines, my code looks something like the following:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include "MersenneTwister.h"  //Random number generator
#include "Particle.h"         //Class that just keeps track of coordinates
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const double SomeGlobalParameters;

//Filling an array with gaussian random numbers

void GaussianDisorder(double EnergyArray[Nx][Ny][Nz], double Sigma)
{
    for (int i=0; i<Nx; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<Ny; j++){
            for (int k=0; k<Nz; k++){
                EnergyArray[i][j][k] = rnd.randNorm(0, Sigma);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Using the above array (read only) to do some calculations

void CalcRates(Particle &charge1, const double (&EnergyArray)[Nx][Ny][Nz], double (&RateArray)[12])
{
    int X1 = charge1.xPosition();
    double NearRate, MagSqr, Dist, OldDist, OldEnergy, NewEnergy;    //Declaring stuff for later
    const double Parity=1.0;

    InitializeStuffAbove(SomeGlobalParameters);           // Give stuff values based on parameters

    if (Dist == 0)
        RateArray[0] = NearRate;
    else
        NewEnergy = Parity*EnergyArray2[X1+1][Y1][Z1] - Efield[0] + Coulomb/(Dist);

int main()
{
    double EnergyArray[Nx][Ny][Nz];
    double RateArray[12];

    GaussianDisorder(EnergyArray);
    CalcRates(charge1, EnergyArray, RateArray);

    return 0;
}
```

My problem is when I change

```
const double Parity=1.0;
```

,which is a local variable, to

```
const double Parity=-1.0;
```

my random number generator in

```
void GaussianDisorder
```

gives a different result, even though I gave it a constant seed, and it gives the same sequence if I run the code multiple times without changing anything. I apologize in advance if I left something important out.

Comment: Run your code under `valgrind` or a similar tool. It's possible you're accessing an array or other object outside its bounds.

Comment: Does InitializeStuffAbove, initialize Dist and Near Rate?

Comment: That phrase "I'm a physicist writing a simulation..." gave me quite a flashback. (And your username reveals a surprising amount about you, but never mind.) Anyway, it's hard for us to help if you don't post enough for us to reproduce the error. My advice: *simplify*. Cut away as much code as you can and verify at every step that the strange behavior persists; get rid of `CalcRates` and `Particle.h`, reduce `GaussianDisorder` to a few calls to `rnd`, and so on. At some point either the cause will jump out at you, or you'll arrive at something small enough to post whole.

Comment: Where is the rest of `CalcRates`? Is only the closing brace missing, or is more missing as well?

Comment: How did you work out that `GaussianDisorder` is returning a different result? I would put some tracing in to output the `EnergyArray` values directly after `GaussianDisorder` is executed, and again before calculating `NewEnergy`. Alternatively, you can make `parity` a parameter of `CalcRates` and try two calls with two arrays; one with parity = 1.0, one with parity = -1.0.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I ran it with an output writing the random numbers to a file as they were being generated in 'GaussianDisorder', so I know how soon in the program things go wrong, but I could certainly continue paring it down. I'll keep removing what I can, and hopefully come up with something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess rnd is declared in MersenneTwister.h, if so function randNorm(const double mean, const double stddev) (from here http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wagnerr/MersenneTwister.h) using function rand().
In order to have different values every time you should use rand and srand jointly. Look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/.